# Solving IVP via Laplace transform

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I have the following initial value problem (IVP):

$$ \mathbf{X}^{\prime}=\mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}, \qquad \mathbf{X}(0)=\mathbf{I} $$

$$ \text { If } \mathbf{x}(s)=\mathscr{L}\{\mathbf{X}(t)\}=\mathscr{L}\left\{e^{\mathbf{A} t}\right\} $$

$$ s \mathbf{x}(s)-\mathbf{X}(0)=\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}(s) \quad \text { or } \quad(s \mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A}) \mathbf{x}(s)=\mathbf{I} $$

I've been a little confused with the use of Identity as opposed to a standard multiplication without the identity. How does $s \mathbf{x}(s)-\mathbf{X}(0)=\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}(s)$ become $(s \mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A}) \mathbf{x}(s)=\mathbf{I}$?

Sorry about the simplicity here but it's always confused me.

Comment: One step that might be particularly tricky is the transition
$$
s \mathbf x(s) - \mathbf A \mathbf x(s) =
(s\mathbf I)\mathbf x(s) - \mathbf A\mathbf x(s) = (s \mathbf I - \mathbf A) \mathbf x(s).
$$
Is this the source of your confusion?

Comment: Note that if we didn't include the identity matrix, the "factorization" step would bring us to $(s - \mathbf A) \mathbf x$. However, there is no obvious interpretation to the expression $s - \mathbf A$ since $s$ is a scalar and $\mathbf A$ is a matrix.